# How to get currency exchange rate of two pairs

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to implement Oanda's 'Currency Pair Units Calculator' using this formula.

https://www1.oanda.com/forex-trading/analysis/currency-units-calculator

```
Margin Available * (margin ratio) / ({BASE}/{HOME Currency} Exchange Rate)
```

My account currency is in USD but I am trading the `GBP/NZD` currency pair. Is there a way in Pinescript to get the current exchange rate between GBP/USD. Once, I have that I will be able to complete the formula.

```
(2000 * 50) / ({syminfo.basecurrency}/{USD} Exchange Rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this

```
exchange_rate = security('OANDA:GBPUSD', "", close)

lotsize = (2000 * 50) / exchange_rate
```